# retrieving files from NAS linux network in PHP

Tags: linux, file, networking, nas

I'm working on a php project where a particular feature will have to access the files stored from an external directory:Network Attached Storage(linux). Lets say the path is /volume1/accounts and this is mounted in the linux server where my site is hosted using apache.  I will have to retrieve files from that directory. is there a way in PHP to do that?  My client says that its already been mounted.

No matter what I do I cant access using these test codes

```
print "<pre>".print_r(scandir("/volume1/accounts/"), true)."</pre>";
print "<pre>".print_r(scandir("192.168.0.233/volume1/accounts"), true)."</pre>";
print "<pre>".print_r(scandir("192.168.0.233:/volume1/accounts"), true)."</pre>";
```

How am I suppose to do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, PHP engine is executed with apache server's privileges. So mounted directory has no permissions or ownership for apache server, It'll be not able to show file lists. Could you try to make directory on /volume1/accounts/ and change ownership and permissions? If apache server is working with apache:apache ownership, please change ownership of directory as same.